# How Install Upgrade compatibility Tool Magento and PhpStorm

Tags: magento2

How to Install Upgrade compatibility Tool Magento 2.4 and PhpStorm?

- To magento 2.4
- To PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

**1. Install tool to Magento 2**

- composer create-project magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool uct
  --repository https://repo.magento.com
- sudo chmod +x ./uct/bin/uct
- uct/bin/uct --help

**Example:**
uct/bin/uct upgrade:check app/code/Module/ -a 2.3.4 -c 2.4.5

**2. Install Tool in PhpStorm Install plugin:**

- Click in: File / Settings…  / Plugins / Click marketplace / install
  Magento PhpStorm

3. After the installation, it is necessary to enable the integration with Magento:
   Go to Settings > Frameworks.

Select the Enable Magento Integration checkbox. See Install PHPStorm plugin topic for more information.

You also need to provide:

- Adobe Commerce or Magento Open Source installation path Adobe
- Commerce or Magento Open Source version (for example, 2.4.4)
- Default license name for new modules (by default, Proprietary)

**3. Inspection code, visualize modules by severity and number of incompatibilities**

- Go to Settings > Editor > Code Style > Inspections
- Click in  > click in Duplicate
- Add name profile: UTC default
- Click in Reset in empty
- Select UTC clic en check
- Click to Apply and OK

**4. Tool to use it**

- Click in: tools / Configure the upgrade compatibility Tool Select
  current: Version: 2.3.3
- Select coming: Version 2.4.4-beta4
- Path to analyse:  /root/project
- Min issue level : WARNING
- Click OK

**5. More info:**

- https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/best-practices/phpstorm/install/
- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-learn/tutorials/upgrade/uct-phpstorm.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

> You also need to provide:
>
> - Adobe Commerce or Magento Open Source installation path Adobe
> - Commerce or Magento Open Source version (for example, 2.4.4)

Unfortunately Open Source version is not applicable:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/use-upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html